# Rust dynamic lib (.so) undefined symbol issue

Tags: c, rust, shared-libraries

I'm currently trying to load an external dynamic lib (dev in C) in rust :

```rust
fn load_challenge(path: &str) {
    unsafe {
        let lib = libloading::Library::new(path).unwrap();
        let step: libloading::Symbol<unsafe extern fn() -> u32> = lib.get(b"step").unwrap();
        step();
    }
}
```

Rust is able to load the lib, then call the C function (called "step" in the example).
That C function (step) is calling an other function (that is called "_banana_printdebug"), that function should be implemented in Rust (and is not embedded in the C dynamic lib).

This is the function header (in C) :

```
extern int _banana_printdebug(char *s, ...);
```

and this is the same function header in Rust:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn _banana_printdebug(s: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char, ...) -> ::std::os::raw::c_int {
    return 0;
}
```

Despite that, at the runtime, I have the following error that I'm not able to fix:

```
target/debug/rustapi: symbol lookup error: ./lib42.so: undefined symbol: _banana_printdebug
```

Any clue on where is the issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to link such executables with `-export-dynamic` linker option.

Comment: Thanks ! Absolutely, it's working with 'rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=-rdynamic"]' in the cargo configuration.